# Add <br /> every 2 images from mysql in a variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to make this code insert a line break after 2 images when there are a total of 4 images. The Code listed below adds the line break after all images are displayed instead of after 2 images. Could someone please help me with this?

```
$images = "";
$i = 0;
while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($imglist)) {
  $style = $info['Style'];
  $imgpath = $info['ImgPath'];
  $standardimg = $info['StandardImg'];
  $colorname = $info['ColorName'];
  $smallimgwidth = $info['SmallImgWidth'];

  $images = $images.
  "<img src='$imgpath/$standardimg-Small.jpg'
  alt = '$mill $style - $colorname'
  title = '$mill $style - $colorname'
  style = 'min-width:35px; max-width:$smallimgwidthpx;' / > ";

  if (mysqli_num_rows($imglist) == 4) {
    if ($i != 0 && $i % 2 == 1) {
      echo '<br />';
    }
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: How do I add the checkmark to your comment instead of an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem **

You are constructing the  tags dynamically but in the process you are adding 
 tags separately.

**Solution**

Add 
 tag to your  tags string being generated.

**Code**

```
$images = $images . '<br />';
```

In place of

```
echo '<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo '<br />';
```

to

```
$images = $images . '<br />';
```

Just like that.

---

I little explanation: you're not 'grouping' *br* output with *image* output, since one goes into a variable (image) and the other is displayed immediately (br).